# Does the Life Cleric ability Disciple of Life apply to the spell Aid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

My first thought was "Oh, yes it does, because it is giving hit points". Then a closer reading seemed to show that no it doesn't, because it isn't *restoring* lost hit points.

I'm still low level so I've been keeping *Aid* in my back pocket, and it's only been used once.  If the Disciple of Life ability did apply, it might actually make me hang on to it for a bit as the spell could be useful for the squishies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is that it depends. Disciple of Life is triggered

> Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher that restores hit points to a creature[...]

As for *Aid*, its effect is quite unique.

> Each target's current and maximum hit points increase by 5 for the duration.

This means that if a target is on X/X health, it goes to X+5/X+5 health. It would be difficult to argue that this counts as "restoring" health, but even if it did, you can't have more hit points than your maximum, and I can't see any argument for Disciple of Life boosting the increase to maximum hit points, so the additional increase to current hit points would be wasted.

On the other hand, if a creature wasn't on full health, for example, if it was on X-10/X, it would go to X-5/X+5. This could certainly be argued as restoring health, meaning that it would trigger Disciple of Life and the target would be on X-1/X+5.

However, there's an even weirder interaction here: the target's current hit points are only increased by 5 for the duration. If you're on 5 hp at the end of 8 hours, you might even die when they disappear. This suggests (to me, at least), that *Aid* doesn't really "restore" hit points, it just sort of loans them.

The real answer here, as so often is, is that you'll have to ask your DM. For a target that isn't on full hit points, you can definitely make a strong case for *Aid* triggering Disciple of Life.

Comment: Perhaps unsurprisingly this is actually the answer my DM ended up going with.  The static +5 to max health for anyone already at max health, and anyone injured healed for 5+ the modifiers up to a fully healed +5 of their max health.  Not as good as it could be fudged potentially but better than the strictest possible interpretation,